# jQuery stop calling other handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Let's say I have labels and I attach two click events to it:

```
$('#l1').bind('click',function(){
 alert('label clicked');
}
$('#l2').bind('click',function(){
 alert('label2 clicked');
}
$('#l3').bind('click',function(){
 alert('label3 clicked');
}

$('label').bind('click',function(){
 if($(this).hasClass('disabled')
return false
}
<label id='l1'>hi</label>
<label id='l2' class="disabled">bye</label>
<label id='l3'>hi</label>
```

Now I don't want the alert to be displayed when the label that has class `disabled` is clicked.
Is it possible to do that?

Note : `alert` is just a dummy thing.. I am performing a set of actions instead of that.. each different on basis of the actual label

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If multiple event handlers are bound to the same element for the same event the handlers are called in the order they were bound. If you call [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) within a particular handler it will stop subsequent handlers being called.

So modify your `$('label').bind()` as follows:

```
$('label').bind('click',function(event){
   if($(this).hasClass('disabled') {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      return false;
   }
}
```

and move that up above your other `.bind()` calls. Then that particular handler will execute first and have the chance to prevent the other handlers from executing.

(Note that [`.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) is not the same as [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)] - the latter stops the event bubbling up the DOM tree but doesn't stop other handlers on the same element.)